# VOMongoRepository fails to connect to MongoDB replicaset with user credentials (Pharo/Voyage)

Tags: mongodb, smalltalk, pharo

I am trying to save a root Object (MyDocument) into a mongoDB with authentication enabled and a ReplicaSet consisting of 3 Nodes (as inserted into mongoUrls)

With this call:
`(VOMongoRepository
        mongoUrls: {'127.0.0.1:27017' . '127.0.0.1:27018' . '127.0.0.1:27019'}
        database: 'myDB'
        username: 'myUser'
        password: 'myPass') enableReplication`

I receive a VOMongoConnectionError without any deeper information.

Trying the same with this:

`VOMongoRepository
mongoUrls: {'myUser:myPass@127.0.0.1:27017/?replicaSet=myRepl' }
database: 'myDB'`

I then receive a VOMongoError "not authorized for Query on myDB.MyDocument"

The credentials are double checked with mongo client and Compass, also the read/write permissions (actually the role is dbOwner).

Interestingly my testDocumentLifeCycle is able to create the object and to send a message to save, that returns without signaling an error, although it does not create the document in MongoDB. But the selectOne: is then returning the VOMongoError:

`| doc |
    MyDocument new
        identity: 'me@there.com';
        save.
    user := MyDocument selectOne: [ :each | each identity = 'me@there.com'].`

Just to mention: the above test for MyDocument class did work with a standalone mongod without authentication enabled. The only thing changed is the repository.

So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: How exactly did you "The credentials are double checked with mongo client and Compass, also the read/write permissions (actually the role is dbOwner)."?  Could you update the question with the information?

Comment: i checked that the credentials work. I used mongo and compass for that.

Comment: Ok.  My guess would be that something is wrong with the encoding for example.  Did you check with e.g. *wireshark* what is actually being sent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually there is a bug in the replicaSet part of VoyageMongo. It is not using the credentials provided. It has been posted at https://github.com/pharo-nosql/voyage/issues/104